# PHP include a php file in a div box whenever one generated

Tags: php

I want to include a php file in a div box whenever one generated through a form.php file
I have here some code allready given 12 boxes in two rows, what i want is growing every time one box and include a new generated php file into new generated div box automaticly, here is my code which need to be improved and to be repaired

```
<?php
$dir=opendir('.') or die ('Cannot open directory');
$file=readdir($dir);
for($j=1; $j < 13; $j++) :
    print '<div style="float:left; width:100px">';
    if(preg_match("/php$/", $file)){
            include($file);
    }
    print '</div>';
    if($j%6==0) print '<div style="clear:both;></div>';
endfor; 
?>
```

thanks in advance for anyhelp

Comment: you're gonna have to rephrase your question and show us some output.

Comment: you have to use AJAX for achieving that, send a request to a php script which will echo back form submissions, but where do you store the form submissions?database?files?

Comment: @GeoPhoenix,  i store submissions into php file and exact this php file i want to include into divbox

Comment: @AdnanShammout what i want it works like a facebook album, whenever i add a new photo, it grows one by one the only difference is instead of photo i need to include a php file, which is fresh generated with a form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `scandir();`

here is the code:

```
<?php
$dir    = 'folder/';
$files = scandir($dir);
$count=2;
foreach($files as $file){
    $count++;
    echo '<div style="float:left; width:100px">';
    if(strpos($file,".php")){
        include($dir.$file);
    }
    echo '</div>';
    if($count==6){echo'<div style="clear:both;></div>';}
}
?>
```

Let me know if you still have confusion

Comment: start $count from 2, to skip . current directory and .. previous directory, you also skip 2 empty divs

Comment: @Prakash thank you but under mac os x i get too much errors with this code, but maybe it depends on OS,

Comment: @HilmiSleymanTunahanDemirkay, you can post your problem here. we are all here to fix that. But, this is what you want in this question. :) good day!

Comment: @Prakash i have allwas such an error output Warning: include(.2.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\deneme\index2.php on line 9 and i dont know if you noticed if we have php file which has name  2.php  and in include method we get allways .2.php ( include(.2.php) ) and because of extra dot infront of 2.php it does not included i think, thanks in advance

Comment: Check, i have made some changes there.
save this file as index.php and make a new folder "folder" and then try the code. this should work for sure. and it doesn't depend on OS

Comment: @Prakash thank you, now i am more near to my goal altough there is some little problems to solve, my first 2 divs(if you add border is better to see) are empyt, its not possible to include files inside, i could not figure out why, do u have any idea ?

Comment: @HilmiSleymanTunahanDemirkay, are you trying to say that you want to add css borders to first two div? please be specific. better ask another question for that. so that it would be more clear and good to other stackexchange users. you can give me the question url here.

Comment: @Prakash, thank you i have solved this problem it was because of . and .. files in a direcotry, pls give me your face id, to stay in contact ;) your help was much appreciated thanks again

Answer (score 1):

or simpler:

```
foreach(glob(dirname(__FILE__)."/*.php") as $i => $file) {
  echo "<div style='float:left; width:100px'>";
  include_once($file);
  echo "</div>";
  if($i%6==0) {
    echo "<div style=\"clear:both;\"></div>";
  }

);
```